# dhtmlxgantt Populate Nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json, dhtmlx

I have a dhtmlx gantt chart in my page, normally it would have work perfectly but now when I have a JSON file with nested array all my output would be `unrecognized` instead. I'm trying to populate the `official name`.

Can Anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

JSON

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "assign_to": {
                "id": 3,
                "employee_id": "28141",
                "official_name": "Hal Jordan",
            },
            "task": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Modeling",
                "description": "3d modeling work"
            },
            "start_date": "2017-06-15",
            "end_date": "2017-06-19"
        },
        {
            "assign_to": {
                "id": 3,
                "employee_id": "28144",
                "official_name": "Kyle Rayner",
            },
            "task": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Composting",
                "description": null
            },
            "start_date": "2017-06-01",
            "end_date": "2017-06-08"
        }
    ]
}
```

Javascript

```
 gantt.config.columns = [
       {name: "assign_to.official_name", label: "Assign To", align: "left", width: 70},
    ];

function initializeGantt() {
   gantt.init("my_scheduler");
   gantt.load("/dashboard/ganttchart_list/5/?format=json");
}

initializeGantt();
```

HTML

```
<div id="my_scheduler" style='width:1405px; height:245px;'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dhtmlx gantt doesn't support nested structure, so you'll need to preprocess your items before loading them to gantt.
Since you know which format you have and which format is expected by gantt (https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__supported_data_formats.html#json ) it shouldn't be a problem.

The most important thing

1. Make sure data items have 'id' property
2. when you define column name like this:

   {name: "assign_to.official_name", label: "Assign To", align: "left", width: 70},

   column name can't be mapped to a property of a nested object, so you'll either have to flatten structure during loading, very roughly, it can be done in following way:
   http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/129d2e043

Or define a column template which would take value from nested object:
http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/9e8e65e85

- please check the console output for a result dataset

Comment: Hello @Alex Klimenkov

Thank you so much, this is perfect! but for my data, its actually coming from a REST API, so if i want to call in the `getData()` function how can I call it? for example `http://127.0.0.1/test/ganttchart_data/5/` 

again I can thank you enough Alex

Comment: Hi! you can request your api manually via ajax get, once you get data from the server - you'll be able to convert it and put into gantt.
If you use jquery and functions from my sample above, it may look following:
`$.get( "/test/ganttchart_data/5/", function(result) {
  gantt.parse(prepareData(result));
}); `
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/